# Return is giving me undefined but console.log give the answer I needed

Tags: node.js

As I am just trying to get weather its found or not found as I have mostly the code which can explain the stuff I guess

and the function form the below is

```js
exports.verifyGroupUser = function(name) {
  const url = 'api.com'
  fetch(url)
    .then(
      function(response) {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
          console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
            response.status);
          return;
        }

        //getting list of habbo in the specific group
        response.json().then(function(data) {
          var isHabbo = ((habbo) => {
            return habbo.name === name;
          })
          var checkbname = data.find(isHabbo);
          //checkbname.then(checkbname)
          //return checkbname;

          var checkx = ((checkbname) => {
            if (checkbname == undefined) {
              return "not found"
            } else {
              return "found"
            }
          })
          console.log(checkx(checkbname)) //gives the answer i need 
          return checkx(checkbname) //gives undefined
        });

      }
    )
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
    });
}
```

calling from another file is like

```js
const portalcheck = require('../controllers/portalcheck')
var ans = portalcheck.verifyGroupUser(req.body.username)
                  console.log(ans)
```

Comment: can promise can do stuff, as the above code return the undefined at no time but the console.log take some second to print out the answer

Comment: How does `checkx` ever return anything other than `"found"`? You're passing `ckeckbname` in it and as per the `isHabbo` function, that's an *object* that has a `name` property. So, `ckeckbname`  will never be equal to the string `"undefined"`, since it's either an object *or* an actual `undefined` variable. In neither case would it pass the equality check.

Comment: sorry VLAZ i messed with some code here but undefined is not string.. as i corrected the code still not working..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: OK, also  - you aren't returning anything properly. You have a `return` statement but in the `then` that doesn't continue the promise chain. At the very least, you should do `return response.json().then(/ * ... */)` but it would be better if broke it up in discrete steps each in a `then`, so it is easier to read and understand.

Comment: @VLAZ, I don't think it's a dupe of that one, the `console.log(ans)` would have logged a pending promise if the asker had put the correct return statements. Since they're already using promises, I think they would have been able to deal with that. The problem is some misconception about where the value from `return` is getting sent, as addressed in my answer and your comment just now.

Comment: @Klaycon it's not returning the promise where the processing is being done.

Comment: @VLAZ I acknowledge this in my prior comment and answer.

Comment: @Klaycon Yes, and the dupe for handling async values goes in depth into how to set up a promise chain or use `async`/`await` properly

Comment: @VLAZ true. I think the asker should read it, but I'm not convinced it would address this particular misconception about what `return` does in a promise callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` only returns the value to the containing function, not any outer one.

So when you do:

```
return checkx(checkbname) //gives undefined
```

that doesn't send the return three functions up to `verifyGroupUser`, it sends the return value only to this function:

```
response.json().then(function(data) { // <-- here
```

This is okay, because that means your `.then()` returns a Promise which will resolve with the "found" or "not found" you're looking for, but you're currently discarding that promise instead of using it. So, return the Promise:

```
return response.json().then(function(data) { // <-- here
```

which will bring that Promise out to your `fetch(url).then(...)`, but you're discarding this promise too, so you'd want:

```
return fetch(url)
  .then(
    function(response) {
```

The end result of this will be that the function `verifyGroupUser` returns a ***Promise*** which will resolve with "found" or "not found". You **need** to deal with this Promise using `.then()` or await, because the function contains asynchronous calls, so you can never get it to synchronously return the "found" or "not found". It must be a Promise and you must deal with it appropriately in your usage.

```
const portalcheck = require('../controllers/portalcheck')
portalcheck.verifyGroupUser(req.body.username).then(function(ans) {
  console.log(ans)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot i just figured out that i was not seeing that i need to return from upper level too